# iOS 5 with ARC - Avoid memory crashes

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am almost done programming a fairly large app which does a lot of talking with a backend, has a lot of caff sounds and displays several animations using sprite sheets. Every XIB files is connected with one `ViewController` and the project uses `ARC` and is targeted `iOS 5.0`.

Testing the app using my `iPhone 5` and using the Simulator works fine. However while beta testing I noticed several people using an iPhone 4 (specially people running many background apps) experience crashes while using the app. The crashes mostly appears when doing animations.

So.. how do I go from here? I tried using instruments to check allocations and leaks. Almost none leaks are occurring, and to be honest, I have a hard time understanding how I can use the allocations measurement. I made all my `IBOutlets _weak` and also all my attributes to a big singleton used throughout the app to _weak.

How should I measure? How should I test that memory gets free'd as intended? How do I avoid these crashes related to low memory?

Comment: Are you certain that it's a memory issue? Have you seen the crash logs?

Comment: consult http://emclstcd.tk in cases when you expect us to guess what's wrong yet you fail to post any code.

Comment: @Mikeal I am not 100p sure, but it seems very likely since they are using an older phone (but with the iOS updated to 6.x) and running a lot apps in the background. Further does the Crashlytics show that they are running with very low free ram and disk space.